# No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light' and Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Hello these are the error
Also in Android sdk Manager didnot find Android Support Library package

[image: Errors Image]

[image: SDK Manager Image]

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  Didnt find build.gradle 

[project files image](https://ibb.co/4YnsT96)

Comment: Time to migrate to Android Studio. You have to add the appcompat libraries (androidx releases). It is not in the sdk support repo.